# $0$-$1$ law for brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I would like to prove the following theorem : Let $B$ be a brownian motion and $\mathcal{F_t}$ its natural filtration. Then for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_{0^{+}}$ we have $\mathbb{P}(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$

Here is my attempt, which has clearly a problem.

Consider $0<\delta$ and $A\in\mathcal{F}_{0^{+}}$. There exists $0<\epsilon<\delta$ such that $A\in\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}$. Now for all $\epsilon<t<\delta$ we have $\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}\perp \sigma(\cup_{t}\sigma(B_t - B_{\epsilon}))$. Then I infer that $\sigma(\cup_{t}\sigma(B_t - B_{\epsilon})) = \mathcal{F}_{\delta}$ but $\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}\subset\mathcal{F}_{\delta}$. Thus $\mathbb{P}(A\cap A) = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(A)$ and we conclude that $\mathbb{P}(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$

I would like to have your opinion on this proof and what can I improve, clearly what I infer concerning $\sigma(\cup_{t}\sigma(B_t - B_{\epsilon})) = \mathcal{F}_{\delta}$ is false or at least not under a good form.

Thank you a lot

Comment: A stronger version of this is known as [Blumenthal-0-1 law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374673/intuition-about-blumenthals-0-1-law) of which you can find a short proof in Karatzas & Shreve, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* chapter 2. Looking at yours quickly: if this were sound then it seems that it should hold for all processes with independent increments (Levy processes). But this does not seem to be the case. You need a [Feller process](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/07/19/properties-of-feller-processes/).

Comment: This follows from the fact that $\mathcal{F}_0$ and $\mathcal{F}_{0^+}$ are equivalent under $P$ and that $B_0 = 0$.

Comment: @Mason Thank you for your comment. I did not understand what do you mean by equivalent sigma algebra ? And what follows from that, the result ?

Comment: Here equivalent under $P$ means that for every $A \in \mathcal{F}_{0^+}$, there is $B \in \mathcal{F}_{0}$ such that $1_A = 1_B$ almost surely. It is known that fir Brownian motion, $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $\mathcal{F}_{t^+}$ are equivalent for all $t$. See page 362 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf